# sorting images in 1 folder according to its labels in yaml file

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml

I have a yaml file which has filename and label and looks like below:

```
- 1003520587_a35cd70a-22ab-4f89-92f8-e44884d6225d_boolean: no-checkbox
- 1003522794_3f24dcc8-60f1-4959-b0f4-d00a9f723a46_boolean: filled
- 1003522794_3f24dcc8-60f1-4959-b0f4-d00a9f723a46_boolean: empty
```

And I have all images in 1 folder. I would like to separate each image according to its label respectively into its folder using python. How would I do it?

I am getting file doesn't exists error using following code.

```
import yaml
import pandas as pd
import shutil
# base folders / template destinations
from_folder =  r'/home/user/Downloads/by_field/abschluss/'
to_folder_base = r'home/user/Downloads/sorted_image/abschluss'

with open('/home/user/Downloads/Yaml/abschluss.yaml', 'r') as stream:
        parsed_yaml=yaml.safe_load(stream)
        for i in parsed_yaml:
            for key in i:
                img_name = key + ".png"
                keyword = i[key]
                to_folder = os.path.join(to_folder_base, keyword)
                os.makedirs(to_folder, exist_ok=True)
                old_img_path = os.path.join(from_folder, img_name)
                new_img_path = os.path.join(to_folder, img_name)
                shutil.move(old_img_path, new_img_path)
```

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

But when I checked using same path the file do exists

I tried by converting yaml to csv file as well using pandas which looks like below:
[attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tERTM.png)

```
import pandas as pd
# base folders / template destinations
from_folder = "/home/user/Downloads/images/Leibteil/"
to_folder_base = "/home/user/Downloads/sorted_image/"

# read in CSV file with pandas
meta_ham = (pd.read_csv('/home/user/Downloads/csv/Leibteil.csv'))
print(meta_ham)
# iterate through each row of csv
for index in range(len(meta_ham)):
    print(index)
    # get image name and corresponding group
    img_name = meta_ham[index] + ".png"
    print(img_name)
    keyword = meta_ham[label]
    print(keyword)
    # make a folder for this group, if it doesn't already exist. 
    # as long as exist_ok is True, then makedirs will do nothing if it already exists
    to_folder = os.path.join(to_folder_base, 'label')
    print(to_folder)
    os.makedirs(to_folder, exist_ok=True)
    # move the image from its original location to this folder
    old_img_path = os.path.join(from_folder, img_name)
    new_img_path = os.path.join(to_folder, img_name)
    shutil.move(old_img_path, new_img_path)
```

But using csv or pandas it throws `Keyerror: 0`

Comment: The error refers to a path that doesn't match the hardcoded constants in this code.

Comment: Now it does, mistakenly I pasted another path in quiestion

Comment: You're going to need to post enough code and data that we can recreate the error, or post the full error trace. I'd suggest finding the old file through os.listdir() then lookup its tags.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check if the directory is created, and if the file exists for the yaml code but for the csv code it is an access error:

```py
# will return row number=index, and column=0
img_name = meta_ham.iloc[index, 0] + ".png"
# will return row number=index, and column=1
keyword = meta_ham.iloc[index, 1]
```